# Compare two column value in dataframe and calculate percentage of values similar in two columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am having dataframe `df`.

I want to compare two columns in dataframe and want to find `accuracy` or percentage of rows which contain same values in both columns.

```
df

predicted_value     actual_value     
0                       1
1                       1
0                       0
1                       1
```

Output- 75% of values are matching between two columns in pandas dataframe.

Comment: please add the `#python` tag. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
acc = (df.predicted_value==df.actual_value).mean()
```

if you want to format the accuracy in percentage:

```
print("%.2f%%"%(acc*100))
```

Comment: I edited my code. `acc` is a value between `[0, 1]` so you need multiply it times 100. I think that is more theoretically-accurate in this way.